# Setting result of find to variable, which has variables within it

Tags: linux, shell, find

I'm trying to find how many files appear with a certain prefix and use this count to then use to add onto the file name to avoid overwriting.

```
#!/bin/sh  

DAY=$(date +%d)                                                          
MO=$(date +%m)                                                           
YR=$(date +%y) 
SE=$(date +%S)                                                             
H=$(date +%H)                                                            
M=$(date +%M)  
DURATION=$(((60 - M) * 60-SE))

PART=$(find /mnt/hgfs/Audio\ Log/ -type f -name "LoggerAudio ${$DAY}-${$MO}-${$YR}\ ${H}*" | wc -l)

arecord -f cd -c 1 -d$DURATION -t raw | lame -b 64 -f -r - /mnt/hgfs/Audio\ Log/"LoggerAudio "$DAY-$MO-$YR\ $H"00 - Part "$PART.mp3
```

It returns finding always `0`.

Comment: `-name "LoggerAudio ${$DAY}-` looks wrong, should be `-name "LoggerAudio ${DAY}-`. Paste some normal `find` command you are using and then replace with variables sequentially.

Comment: @fedorqui, doh it's a mistype I failed to spot. Thanks works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in comments, the problem lies in using `${$var}` instead of just `${var}`:

```
PART=$(find /mnt/hgfs/Audio\ Log/ -type f -name "LoggerAudio ${$DAY}-${$MO}-${$YR}\ ${H}*" | wc -l)
                                                               ^       ^      ^
```

so you need to use:

```
PART=$(find /mnt/hgfs/Audio\ Log/ -type f -name "LoggerAudio ${DAY}-${MO}-${YR}\ ${H}*" | wc -l)
```